# alert/background music in C .exe files

Tags: c, windows, audio, alert, beep

So recently I've been trying to create some sort of alert sounds in a C based menu driven program. I was wondering if there are any other ways instead of these, that I can use to play some music file(in background, without showing it to user in their .exe run) or any kind of small beep sounds. As these aren't working. As \a has no windows support now(atleast not on my win-7 x64 or win-8 x64), but works on only MAC OS X terminal

---

*I've tried successfully in `<html>` and cmd(.bat) files so there has to be some support in C*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <dos.h>
int main( void ){
    int x = 10;
    while (printf("%d ", x) && x--> 0)
        Beep(500, 100);/*using two pre-defined doesn't work (output change i get->just gives a fade in effect) Beep(freq, duration)*/
    printf("\a");//BEL character ASCII code 7(output change i get->pause the output screen til keypress)
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: check this  [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)